# Install java on Linux through shell without apt-get

Tags: java, linux, shell, wget, apt-get

I'd like to run multicraft on one of my servers.

After some intensive debugging/installing I realised the server didn't yet have a Java Runtime Environment. I figured it would be easy to install, but that is where is was wrong.

sudo apt-get install sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jre
   sudo: apt-get: command not found

So I figured I had to get the installer through `wget` but I couldn't find an URL to do so.

My Linux version is:

> version 2.6.18-194.8.1.el5.028stab070.4PAE
>   root@rhel5-build-x32
>   gcc version 4.1.2 20080704
>   Red Hat 4.1.2-46

So how do I install Java on Linux through the shell without `apt-get`?

---

When I try `yum`:

```
yum install sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jre 
Determining fastest mirrors *** removed bits here *** 
Excluding Packages in global exclude list 
Finished Setting up Install Process 
No package sun-java6-bin available. 
No package sun-java6-jre available. 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror 
Nothing to do
```

Comment: What is the distribution running on the server? If it is not a Debian compatible one, you should not use `apt-get`or `aptitude` (for instance CentOS & Redhat use `yum`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions:

1. You have to download required jdk version from the site: http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp

Put the downloaded jdk into your required folder,

Here, I am creating a new folder as a java inside the `/etc` folder and placing my `jdk` inside the `/etc/java` folder. It will look like `/etc/java/jdk-6u21-linux-i586.bin`

Now change the permission of your file through `chmod` to accessing installer.txt file while extracting it. Change the permission by typing the following command on your terminal. `sudo chmod +x jdk-6u21-linux-i586.bin`

Now `execute` the file by typing this command on your terminal like `sudo ./jdk-6u21-linux-i586.bin`

It will create a folder inside the `/etc/java/` and it will looks like `/etc/java/jdk1.6.0_21`

And our java is install now we our going to setting the class path of our java for this what we have to do is. Just type this command on your terminal `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc` and it will open a editor, and now we have to put export `JAVA_HOME=/etc/java/jdk1.6.0_21` at the last line of our editor and after it we have to do is export `PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

It will looks like : export J`AVA_HOME=/etc/java/jdk1.6.0_21export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

Now save it and close it. `And restart your system or type it in your terminal source ~/.bashrc`

Finally, our java is ready just type java -version on your terminal and it will return java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)